# When I make an http fetch request I get a type assignment error where type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform

I am making http get request, return type is map, I get error while converting to list

thrown error

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

API returns in xml type

```
  Future<List<Haber>> haberGetir() async {
    final Xml2Json xml2json = Xml2Json();
    String haberUrl =
        'https://www.trthaber.com/xml_mobile.php?tur=xml_genel&kategori=ekonomi&adet=20&selectEx=yorumSay,okunmaadedi,anasayfamanset,kategorimanset';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(haberUrl));

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonRes;
      List<Haber> list;

      xml2json.parse(res.body);
      var jsonString = xml2json.toParker();
      jsonRes = jsonDecode(jsonString);
      print(jsonRes);
      list = (jsonRes as List).map((deger) => Haber.fromJson(deger)).toList();
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          list;
        });
      }
      return list;
    } else {
      return throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

Model classes

```dart
class Welcome4 {
  Welcome4({
    this.haberler,
  });

  Haberler? haberler;
}

class Haberler {
  Haberler({
    this.haber,
  });

  List<Haber>? haber;
}

class Haber {
  Haber({
    this.haberManset,
    this.haberResim,
    this.haberLink,
    this.haberId,
    this.haberVideo,
    this.haberAciklama,
    this.haberMetni,
    this.haberKategorisi,
    this.haberTarihi,
    this.mansetResim,
    this.izlesId,
    this.yorumSay,
    this.okunmaadedi,
    this.anasayfamanset,
    this.kategorimanset,
  });

  Anasayfamanset? haberManset;
  String? haberResim;
  String? haberLink;
  String? haberId;
  String? haberVideo;
  Anasayfamanset? haberAciklama;
  Anasayfamanset? haberMetni;
  HaberKategorisi? haberKategorisi;
  String? haberTarihi;
  String? mansetResim;
  String? izlesId;
  Anasayfamanset? yorumSay;
  Anasayfamanset? okunmaadedi;
  Anasayfamanset? anasayfamanset;
  Anasayfamanset? kategorimanset;

  factory Haber.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Haber(
      haberManset: json['haber_manset'],
      haberResim: json['haber_resim'],
      haberLink: json['haber_link'],
      haberId: json['haber_id'],
      haberVideo: json['haber_video'],
      haberAciklama: json['haber_aciklama'],
      haberMetni: json['haber_metni'],
      haberKategorisi: json["haber_kategorisi"],
      haberTarihi: json["haber_tarihi"],
      mansetResim: json["manset_resim"],
      yorumSay: json["yorumSay"],
      okunmaadedi: json["okunmaadedi"],
      kategorimanset: json["kategorimanset"],
    );
  }
}

List<Haber> haberList = [];

class Anasayfamanset {
  Anasayfamanset({
    this.cdata,
  });

  String? cdata;
}

enum HaberKategorisi { EKONOMI, DNYA }
```

Comment: what does `print(jsonRes)` show?

Comment: @pskink   {haberler: {haber: [{haber_manset: Türkiye'nin ihracat serüveni, haber_resim: https://trthaberstatic.cdn.wp.trt.com.tr/resimler/1886000/ihracat-aa-1886862.jpg, haber_link: haber/ekonomi/turkiyenin-ihracat-seruveni-720801.html, haber_id: 720801, haber_video: null, haber_aciklama:

Comment: so your response is a map, not list

Comment: I can't find how to convert it to a list

Comment: what does print(jsonRes.runtimeType) show?

Comment: @pskink  _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

Comment: @pskink 
If I do it as a map, how will I project the data to the screen, I need to be able to transfer it to the list in the model class.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from the comments to your question, the response you get is a map that has a list inside it.
This is the format you have:

```
{"haberler":{"haber":[...]}}
```

which is not a list but a

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>>>
```

You have some options here.

1. Modify the response sent to you to contain a list directly. I suggest this because the response you get seems to have an unnecessary level of nesting (at least that is how it looks like).
2. As far as I understand from the format, you can modify how you handle the response because the list you are trying to access is inside the map. You can do this:

```
var jsonLs = jsonRes["haberler"]["haber"] as List
list = (jsonLs as List).map((deger) => Haber.fromJson(deger)).toList();
```